# How to make a click event for add/sub value for each jquery sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying but failed to make a jquery event to increment/decrement input value on click add/sub button. It will work for each row separately.

```html
 <tr>
    <td>
        <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
        <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
        <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
        <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
        <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
        <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
        <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
        <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
        <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
    var value  = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    $(this).siblings('input').value = ++value;
 });
 $(document).on('click', '#sub', function(){
    var value  = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    $(this).siblings('input').value = --value;
 });
```

Comment: I am able to find out that input and its value but cannot able to set a new value on click the following button

Comment: @BelalKhan, `$(this).siblings('input').val(parseInt(value, 10) - 1);`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks, that's work nicely, but I don't know why you use (value, 10) here

Comment: as `.val()` return string its always better to convert the `value` to `integer`

Comment: Many many thanks @Satpal

Comment: OK, no same ID for multiple elements in the same document. use classes instead for similar things. and then you can use the same classNames for jQuery selection for event binding too instead of ID selection. example: `$(".add").click(handler)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.val()` method to get/set its inputs value.

Identifiers in HTML must be *unique*, I would recommend you assign common class to button elements and use [Class Selector `('.class')`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to target them.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
  $(this).siblings('input').val(function(_, value) {
    if (value == undefined)
      return 0;
    
    return parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
  });
  
});
$(document).on('click', '.sub', function() {
  $(this).siblings('input').val(function(_, value) {
    if (value == undefined)
    return 0;
    
    return parseInt(value, 10) - 1;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <button class="sub">SUB</button>
    <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
    <button class="add">ADD</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="sub">SUB</button>
    <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
    <button class="add">ADD</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="sub">SUB</button>
    <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
    <button class="add">ADD</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="sub">SUB</button>
    <input type="number" name="" id="" value="1">
    <button class="add">ADD</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this -

```
$(this).siblings('input').val(--value);
```

in place of -

```
$(this).siblings('input').value = --value;
```